# Material Design Input with currency format

Tags: angularjs, material-design

Is there an input in Material Design that takes a format as a parameter.  I specifically need the currency format.

If this is not available, what approach would you suggest to achieve this functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could use some decimal formatter, then put the character of currency sign before the number.

Comment: I tried something similar, but then I have to set the input's type to text which loses the up and down buttons and the numbers only restriction.

Comment: I was hoping for something more encapsulated like Kendo's numeric text box.

Comment: You can create your own directive from a jquery mask plugin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this, add the icon as the currency and use the following directive for masking,

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" layout="column">
    <md-content  >
      <md-input-container class="md-icon-float">
        <label>Price</label>
        <md-icon md-font-icon="fa fa-money"></md-icon>
        <input  currency-mask ng-model="amount" id="sInput" />
      </md-input-container>
     </md-content>
  </body>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('currencyMask', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {

      var formatNumber = function(value) {

        value = value.toString();
        value = value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, "");
        var parts = value.split('.');
        parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$&,");
        if (parts[1] && parts[1].length > 2) {
          parts[1] = parts[1].substring(0, 2);
        }

        return parts.join(".");
      };
      var applyFormatting = function() {
        var value = element.val();
        var original = value;
        if (!value || value.length == 0) {
          return
        }
        value = formatNumber(value);
        if (value != original) {
          element.val(value);
          element.triggerHandler('input')
        }
      };
      element.bind('keyup', function(e) {
        var keycode = e.keyCode;
        var isTextInputKey =
          (keycode > 47 && keycode < 58) || // number keys
          keycode == 32 || keycode == 8 || // spacebar or backspace
          (keycode > 64 && keycode < 91) || // letter keys
          (keycode > 95 && keycode < 112) || // numpad keys
          (keycode > 185 && keycode < 193) || // ;=,-./` (in order)
          (keycode > 218 && keycode < 223); // [\]' (in order)
        if (isTextInputKey) {
          applyFormatting();
        }
      });
      element.bind('blur', function(evt) {
        if (angular.isDefined(ngModelController.$modelValue)) {
          var val = ngModelController.$modelValue.split('.');
          if (val && val.length == 1) {
            if (val != "") {
              ngModelController.$setViewValue(val + '.00');
              ngModelController.$render();
            }
          } else if (val && val.length == 2) {
            if (val[1] && val[1].length == 1) {
              ngModelController.$setViewValue(val[0] + '.' + val[1] + '0');
              ngModelController.$render();
            } else if (val[1].length == 0) {
              ngModelController.$setViewValue(val[0] + '.00');
              ngModelController.$render();
            }
            applyFormatting();
          }
        }
      })
      ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        if (!value || value.length == 0) {
          return value;
        }
        value = value.toString();
        value = value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, "");
        return value;
      });
      ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        if (!value || value.length == 0) {
          return value;
        }
        value = formatNumber(value);
        return value;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/hqjdmOBRAfq5Y1KwNF5H?p=preview)**

Comment: Very nice.  Thank you for that.  :)

Comment: Thanks a lot brother!

Answer (score 2):

I think the best option is to use: [ng2-currency-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-currency-mask) directive for clean coding.

```
<input currencyMask [(ngModel)]="value" [options]="{ prefix: 'R$ ', thousands: '.', decimal: ',', precision: 2 }"/>
```